# In Docker, how do I clean up volumes/containers/etc that have not been used for X amount of time? (Days, Weeks, Months?)

Tags: docker

I know how to clean up *ALL* unused images/containers/volumes/etc.
However, I don't know how to clean up only the images that have not been used for a period of time.

It doesn't have to be exactly a week, but I need a command or series of commands to clean up only the ones that haven't been used for a while.

I want to keep the images that are frequently used in order to save time.

#### Prune everything:

```
$ docker system prune -a --volumes
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all volumes not used by at least one container
        - all images without at least one container associated to them
        - all build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

#### Prune evertying except volumes:

```
$ docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
```

Comment: How would you define "used"? Starting a container based on the image? And then how would you consider an image that is used as base for another image? You can't really delete its layers...

Comment: I would defined used as any image or layer that was used/created during a `docker build` or 'docker run` or similar command. When you use the docker run the `docker image rm $imageName` command it deletes the image and all layers associated to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the until filter - `until (<timestamp>) - only remove images created before given timestamp`

`The until filter can be Unix timestamps, date formatted timestamps, or Go duration strings (e.g. 10m, 1h30m) computed relative to the daemon machine’s time.`

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: does this work for volumes?